# how to update the table values base on two or more conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to learning MYSQL. I want to update the table based on two conditions.I have two tables prices, example.
The **prices table** have three columns

->ID

->UPC

->PRICE

and **example table** have three columns

->UPC

->PRICE

->EXAMPLE_ID

I want to update the prices table price based on example table price.
If UPC is matched in both tables and id="any number" then i want to update the prices table.
the below query i am using

```
update prices p inner join 
example e  on p.UPC=e.UPC AND p.id=6
set p.price= e.example_price;
```

Thank you.

Comment: you said, ID & UPC should match, and in query you are matching UPC with UPC. Either you said wrong or query is wrong

Comment: Go on. Try a little harder

Comment: make and condition as where p.id=6

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set p.price to be the result of a sub query like this:

```
UPDATE prices p SET p.price = (SELECT e.price FROM example e WHERE e.upc = p.upc AND p.id = 6);
```

Comment: I am getting Subquery returns more than 1 row error.

Comment: i have more than one row with id=6;

Comment: If you have more than one row, the problem comes from the structure of your tables. According to your query, condition `p.UPC=e.UPC AND p.id=6` should make it possible to have only one line at most.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

```
UPDATE prices p JOIN 
example e USING (UPC) 
SET p.price= e.example_price WHERE p.id=6
```

It joins both the tables using UPC and sets price when the ID of prices table is 6.